# Which package is required for \Z to work as the symbol for the set of integers?

Tags: fonts, symbols

According to http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:Z#The_Set_of_Integers,

\Z should produce the symbol for the set of integers, but I have not been able to find the package that enables this feature.

I have tried `dsfont` as well as `amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb` but none of them seem to have it.

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
```

and then using it in equations?

EDIT: forgot, that it needs amsfonts package.

Comment: I actually ended up doing that just now, but I still wonder whether there's a package that predefines them.

Comment: @merlin2011 If there is such, it is definitely not a good one. For me, `\Z` refers to `\mathcal{Z}` as I don't work with integers, but I do work with a "zero machine" called this way. Predefining shortcuts like this if you don't use them is a bad idea. Define only such symbols you really use.

Comment: Either `amsfonts` or `amssymb`; the latter loads the former, and is usually recommended.